# Sending xml raw data always null

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

i am struggling wih posting xml raw data to my webapi controller, the passed value is always null on the controller side....

Here my code:

Request

```
Query.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: axForm.EndPoint + "api/items/PostXmlData",
            contentType: "application/xml",
            data: {xmlData: axForm.QvXmlForm},
            async: false,
            success: function (response) { 
                $('#tab1').append(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
                //alert(xhr.responseText); 
            }
        }); 

    }
```

- webapi method

  ```
  [ActionName("PostXmlData")]
  [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
  [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
  public IHttpActionResult PostXmlData([FromBody]string xmlData)
  {
      ...
  }
  ```
- Sent xml data:

> 

Comment: try this, I am not posting it as an answer since i haven't tried it myself.

`public IHttpActionResult PostXmlData()
{
  string xml = "";
    if(Request.InputStream != null){
        var stream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
        var xml = stream.ReadToEnd();  // xml might be encoded, decode it before using.      
    }
}`

Comment: is there a reason you want "xmlData" as a string and not a de-serialized object? Dealing with strongly types objects is much easier than messing with strings.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the issue.
For this ajax call I am using just a simple type and not complex type.
The link below helped me:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data,-part-1

The data part of the ajax call has to be like that when dealing with simple types:

```
data: {"": axForm.QvXmlForm}
```

I appreciated your help.

Patric